# SerialPort.GetPortNames returns same port multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

```
SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

is returning the following array:

```
{ "COM1", "COM5", "COM5", "COM5", "COM5", "COM5", "COM5" }
```

It normally only has each name once. Working around this is very easy, but does anyone know why it would ever do this?

Comment: This method retrieves the names from the registry. Perhaps it has invalid data. [GetPortNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MethodMan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a lot more information about your specific environment, including machine configuration and registry information, it's impossible to answer for sure. But most likely the (unsatisfying) answer is that `GetPortNames()` is just doing the best it can with the information available to it.

I.e. it examines the registry to see what ports exist and returns a list of them to you. In some cases, the same COM port number may be reused by multiple devices, or even multiple uses of the same device (depending on driver), causing the port number to be listed in the registry more than once.

Indeed, in some cases you may get a COM port name returned that isn't even valid at the moment. I.e. some device that did exist at some time, but which was removed/disconnected/etc. and is no longer usable.

It's a classic "garbage-in, garbage-out" issue.

For related information on the question, you might like to check out these Stack Overflow questions:

[GetPortNames() returns stale data/Remove stale comport entries in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19823450)
[SerialPort.GetPortNames() is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8218153)
[SerialPort.GetPortNames() behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2754857)

Comment: Not sure why that was voted down. Good thorough answer and +1 for garbage in garbage out.

Comment: I'm thinking it is multiple uses of the same device. It only happens rarely, and the workaround is to make a list of unique string names from the names given. I do handshaking with each device to determine which COM it's on, so this is not blocking me, I just thought it was strange. I don't understand why Microsoft would run this from the registry as opposed to some kind of "live" data in the OS. The whole Serial Port API has weird mojo for my money.